# Make fancybox (jquery) use server-side (php) resizing for images

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

Is there a way for fancybox (jquery) to use serverside resizing (preferably php) instead of just using client resizing ? Anyone tried doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this approach is that the server-side scripts (PHP in this case) have finished running once the page has been sent to the visitor's browser (client).  Client-side resizing techniques are used because the client-side scripts (jQuery in this case) have access to the client browser and can base their sizing off of environment variables such as the browser's viewport size.

Bottomline: While you can **pre**-size on the server side, perhaps serving up a range of image sizes, or including some viewport/sizing info in the request, but no server-side technique will be able to match the level of control you'll have on the client side.

Comment: Yes, but jquery /javascript/ triggers and event that can be used to make an AJAX call serving the server side resizer with needed data and showing output after server finished resizing. I am still however trying to figure out the bandwith used vs processing power used effectivness.

Comment: I think the best approach here would be to store a range of image sizes on the server and let JavaScript decide which size to request at pageload.  Storing multiple sizes is the approach taken by many CMSs, and seems to work for most.

Comment: thx for the idea, i already cache loads of resolutions so probably ill just hit up php with javascript to find the most appropriate size from the database of cached images and serve it up. Thx

Comment: Sounds good.  When you come up with a solution, please post it as an answer so that the community can learn from your experience.  Cheers~